# How can i include an eternal library such as facebook sdk in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1

I want to use facebook php sdk in symfony. I google and found that i need to go through the autoload.php first..

autoload.php

```
$loader->add('facebook',__DIR__.'/../vendor/facebook/lib/facebook/facebooks.php');
$loader->register();
```

The $loader here is an instance of the ClassLoader class

I modified the facebook sdk to have a folder structure as vendor/facebook/lib/facebook/facebooks.php

facebooks.php

```
require 'src/facebook.php';
class facebooks extends facebook{

}
```

I want to be able to use the facebook instance in my controller.
Here is all i've tried but still it does not work..

How can I fix this out  ?

Answer (score -1):

There is [FOSFacebookBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle) for you, checkout **installation** section.

Comment: Yea that's okay but i want this attempt of mine to work bcause i have more libraries i want to laod

Comment: If your stuff is organized in namespaces, just move it inside your bundle under a `Facebook` folder, then reference classes as `YourBundle\Facebook\ClassName`.

Comment: lol downvoting a 2y old answer w/ no reason, that's getting a life.